# Screenshots getting piled up in the folder on Sierra

Tags: finder, screen-capture, macos

When using Yosemite and El Capitan, I set up a folder where screenshots are sent by default. Once screenshots were taken, they'd be added to the bottom of the folder, all in a grid and such.

Ever since I upgraded to Sierra, however, the screenshots, even though sent to the right folder, are put in some random position in it. As a result, they get piled up on top of other screenshots that were already there. Is there anyway of fixing this? What could be causing it?

---

I realized this is happening on all of my folders, not just the screenshots one. Whenever I used to add new stuff to a folder, it'd get sent to the bottom on that folder, and now it gets piled up on top of the item on the left side of the fifth row (the bottom-most row on the window before I resize or maximize it).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your folder to Arrange by some criterion - name, date etc

Select the open window, then View Menu > Arrange by >

[image]

Alternatively, use Clean Up By to sort them once, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  to get the Folder Options, select elect Arrange By None & Sort by > Snap to Grid.

[image]

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. That effectively splits and groups the images according to whatever criterion I choose. What I want is just for the new images to appear at the bottom of the folder, like they used to, instead of piled up in random places.

Comment: Added an alternative method, though I'm pretty sure Arrange by Date would have done what you wanted.

Comment: Was just trying this alternative method, and the images still seem to be piled up, though trying to move them sends 'em to the bottom at once — not sure what's up with that. As for _arrange by date_, the last time I tried it it reversed the order of the images, putting the most recent at the top — there's seems to not be a way of reversing the order.

Comment: yes, date will sort new to the top. The alternative method requires you to Clean Up by something once, which will them move them from their random locations, then none & snap should do what you want, assuming you don't manually drag anything in there, otherwise it will go wherever there's a space.

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding something, not conveying something properly, or the behavior since the upgrade to Sierra indeed changed in someway. I have the "sort by snap to grid" option chosen, but new images keep getting added on top of others. The Finder window shows, by default, 5 rows of images before scrolling, and for some reason new images get added on top of the leftmost image on the 5th row, always. Doing a simple "clean up" (by nothing in particular) sends the images to the bottom most times, but it sometimes sends the one on the back instead... Trying to move sends the new one down.

Comment: Actually, just realized this is happening on every folder, not just the screenshots one. Just downloaded a pdf to another folder, and it got added on top of the leftmost item on the 5th row (meaning the bottom most row without expanding the window or scrolling) :\